# Convert hashed byte array into String

Tags: java, string, hash, arrays

If I do something like

```
int keyLength = 160; // because SHA1 generates 160-bit hashes
int iterations = 20 * 1000; //standard is 2000 but let's be more secure here

KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), generateSalt(), iterations, keyLength);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
byte[] hash = keyFactory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
```

How do I convert this hash into String so it can be saved into DB?I tried `new String(hash, "UTF-8");` but that gives malformed characters like `l��0\�w�c��Q�`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode the byte array into a [Base64 string](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html), then decode it back to a byte array when you read it from the database.  Note that the encoded string will be around 33% larger than the original byte array.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll always consume your key as a `byte[]` in your application it would be far better to save it as a BLOB binary object itself in the database. You'll save yourself from conversion errors.